# How do I call the trim function on a Kohana 3.2 validation object?

Tags: php, kohana

How can I call the **trim** function on a validation object in Kohana 3.2? I am using:

```
$post = Validation::factory($this->request->post());
$post->rule('Email', 'trim');
```

Answer (score 4):

Validation objects are read only as of 3.2. Filter the input before creating the Validation object like so:

```
$post = array_map('trim', $this->request->post()); // $post[key] = expression; if it is for one specific value

$post = Validation::factory($post);

// set validation rules etc
```

Comment: so$post = Validation::factory($post);

Comment: Yep, and do all the filtering to the $post array you want before that line.

Comment: but kohana 3.2 have't method filter, and i Still don't know how get validated data

Comment: The removed filtering feature manipulated the $post array after the creation of the Validation object, but before the validating. That feature is removed, so now the manipulating must be done before the creation of the Validation object.

Comment: I think it very inconveniently as compared was ((

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Darsstar reply - if you need recursive version of `array_map`, check out [Arr::map](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Arr#map) function:

```
$post = Arr::map('trim', $this->request->post());
```