# ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Validate' not found

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

Am getting an error while trying to integrate validation in kohana. following are error details

Error message title

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Validate' not found
```

APPPATH\classes\Controller\home.php [ 24 ]

```
19  {
20       $_model = Model::factory('home');
21       
22       if ($this->request->method() == HTTP_Request::POST)
23       {
24           $post = Validate::factory($_POST)
25             ->filter(TRUE, 'trim')
26             ->filter('txt_name', 'strtolower')
27  
28             ->rule('txt_name', 'not_empty')
29             ->rule('txt_name', 'regex', array('/^[a-z_.]++$/iD'))
```

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Kohana are you using? For [Kohana 3.3](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/security/validation) it should be:

`Validation::factory($_POST)`

Also you can use `$this->request->post()` instead of `$_POST`

Looks like the filter method was deprecated from Kohana 3.2 so you could do the following as suggested here: [How do I call the trim function on a Kohana 3.2 validation object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906320/how-do-i-call-the-trim-function-on-a-kohana-3-2-validation-object)

```
$post = array_map('trim', $this->request->post());

$post = Validation::factory($post)
    ->rule('txt_name', 'not_empty')
    ->rule('txt_name', 'regex', array('/^[a-z_.]++$/iD'));
```

Or alternatively, you could use http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/filters

Comment: Thanks. I changed Validate::factory($_POST) to Validation::factory($_POST) and now it fixed. But now the error moved to next line. and the message is ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined method Validation::filter()

Comment: Looks like the filter method is not available as of 3.2/3.3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906320/how-do-i-call-the-trim-function-on-a-kohana-3-2-validation-object

Comment: Yes. Thanks for helping me :-) Found this thread for correcting remaining issues http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/security/validation